# UIButton does not position itself correctly and not showing up in some devices - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton

I'm trying to align in center two buttons in a single-view application. I don't want to use auto-layout, i try to solve this case programmatically. So in my ViewController.m, in the ViewDidLoad() function, i've put the following code:

```
_firstButton.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.frame.size.height/2.0-235);
_secondButton.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, _secondButton.frame.size.height/2.0+(self.view.frame.size.height*0.9));
```

The secondButton is correctly positioned in any screen, on any device and on any simulator. The firstButton is positioned right only in iphone 5 and 5S simulators, but it does not even show up in my iPhone 5C device or the iPhone 6 & 6 Plus simulators.

What am i doing wrong, what do i miss here?

Thanks in advance

ps: objective-c noob here, sorry if that's a too dumb question

Comment: Move your code to `- viewDidLayoutSubviews` of `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `viewDidLoad` the frame is not set yet. I recommend you to do it in `viewWillAppear`

Comment: yes, that was it! I'd never think of that, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

### Be sure it is NOT a dumb question.

As a little help, I can tell you I find easier to handles layout with **main xib** with **auto layout**.

**Otherwise**, for multiple screens sizes, you could manage sizes or positions as relatives to actual screen size : `UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds`, for instance, in case of sizes :

```
   let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

   let sreenHeight = screenSize.height
   let screenWidth = screenSize.width

   let cardwidth = screenSize.width * 0.47
   let cardheight = screenSize.height * 0.47

   let ViewBackGround = UIView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cardwidth * 0.8, cardwidth))
```